# API key not valid Kudan (AR) xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, kudan

I'm a beginner to Unity and try to make a simple AR app (IOS). I followed some tutorials and faced a problem. I set the API key and BundleID in Unity correct and changed the "enable Bitcode" to NO. When I want to build & run the application I got the message:

[Failed to code sign "Unity-iPhone"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1p8x.png)

"Fix Issue" the following message:

[An App ID with Identifier 'eu.kudan.ar' is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dxdA.png)

When I change the Bundle Identifier to my own team and app name the 'obstacle' seems to be fixed. When the build is ready and the application starts (on the device) the following error occured:

```
Kudan.AR.KudanTracker:Start()

[ line 374] 
(Filename:  Line: 374)

2016-08-27 02:56:06.005 ar[633:164754] Error verifying license key for bundleID: eu.bart.CarAR error: (null)
2016-08-27 02:56:06.005 ar[633:164754] API key not valid
```

What am i doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: In order to use the development keys, you need to use a wildcard provisioning profile. It looks like an asterisk, *. Intel of all people do a pretty good tutorial on how to make one. https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/walkthrough-obtain-dev-provisioning-profile

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try with another key.
https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys
And it's normal if it doesn't work with own app name.